# Cómo abrir explorador de archivos en una aplicacion WEB en una ruta especifica

Tags: php, javascript, html

Lo que necesito es abrir el explorador de archivos desde el cliente, en un folder especifico. En lugar de que abra siempre en el ultimo que el usuario utilizó. Se que no es posible por motivos de seguridad. Mi duda es si existe una solución en donde pueda utilizar código de escritorio solo para esa parte de mi aplicación, o alguna solución alternativa para poder visualizar los archivos. Igual, si la respuesta es un "No se puede", ¿Existe algún lugar donde pueda revisar la justificación de seguridad de por que no puedo realizar esa acción?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no se puede, porque no sabes desde donde abrio la pagina web. Es mas, suponer que existe la ruta es un error. Las cuestiones de seguridad es que el navegador no tiene acceso al sistema operativo sobre el cual esta montado. sabe algunas cosas, pero no puede permitirle acceder a una pagina a las partes internas del SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segun la RFC 1867 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1867) no existe ningún atributo que permita seleccionar la carpeta. De todas formas,  en las especificaciones se plantea que el atributo VALUE puede establecer un archivo "sugerido", pero eso depende de la implementación de cada browser.
Respecto al motivo, podes leer algo en esa RFC, además tené en cuenta que el path a un folder específico tambien depende del SO,  por ejemplo, las rutas en windows y linux se escriben diferente.

Como solución alternativa, podes programar e instalar en la pc de cada cliente un programa que actue como servidor WebSocket (que escuche en el localhost, para que no necesite certificados ssl), te conectas por javascript y "hablas" con ese programa para hacer lo que necesites, inclusive enviar archivos de la carpeta que quieras.